# Get path from generic file in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, xamarin

I need to get the full path of the file that the user selects on your device. This file can be of any extension, I am using the code below, but the "data" is always to null.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();

MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.Singleton;

intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
intent.SetType("file/*");
StartActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Method OnActivityResult()

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Comment: `Uri uri = data.getData();`

Comment: What kind of project is this code in? It may not work, if done from a PCL.

Comment: @PedroOliveira the data is always to null.

Comment: @Blanthor is c#. I'm using Xamarin Android